# How to have the execution of a method (called by an interpolation) only after ngOnInit() finishes

Tags: angular

How to have the execution of a method (called by an interpolation) only after ngOnInit() finishes. In ngOnInit() i have some initializations made by http calls with async / await and the method called by interpolation needs those initializations.

Comment: First of all you would want to avoid calling functions in template, they are called on each change detection and hurts performance, in worst case you can fall into what seems like an infinite loop. If you were to present your usecase more with code, there is probably an alternative solution.

Comment: It's true, I understood what you mentioned about not using methods in templates. I removed this method from my code and the execution became much lighter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the .html

```
<div *ngIf="ready">
  <p>{{someFunction()}}
</div>
```

on the .ts

```
ready: boolean = false;

data: any;

constructor( private http: HttpClient){}
ngOnInit(){
  // random http function like the one you mention
  this.http.get('someUrl').subscribe(data => {this.ready = true})
}
```

The `*ngIf="ready"` will asure that the function will be called only when that div is rendered.

This is just a workaround your problem. I think calling methods from the template with interpolation is not a good practice on Angular. Maybe someone else can elaborate more on that topic, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If it did, glad it helped and please mark it us correct answer with the checkmark.